# Multiple columns within TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm creating an iOS app and will to create Table view cell with 3 columns inside of it. For example instagram profile page that contains the user information. Can this be achieved within xcode? I'm using a storyboard.

[image]

Comment: If you're using ios6, you might be looking for a `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very much possible in XCode. You'll have to create a custom `UITableViewCell` to create this. In your custom `UITableViewCell` you'll have to create different components as per your need. [image]

I believe the yellow box in above pic is what you want to achieve. For this :

1. You'll have to create one custom cell with 3 `UIImageView`

**EDIT :**

[image]

1. In your `UITableViewCell` you'll have to create one `UIImageView` to show the profile picture.
2. Two `UILabel` one for the statistic. And, one for text.
3. One `UIButton` for Following.

Comment: Thank you! The part I want to achieve is the section with the profile picture and it have photos followers and following. Will that also be a custom cell with 5 UITableCells inside?

Comment: Can you put the screen shot of what you want to achieve so we can help you more.

Comment: if you look at the screen shot you posted of the instagram profile. I want to achieve the same structure of of the profile picture next to the follow button, With UILabels photos, followers, following on top of the button. I attached a photo in my original post

Comment: @EricOboite : I have edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: thank you! Very helpful! Do you have any idea how they created the borders between the labels, images and button?

Comment: @EricOboite It's an image. You can keep it a part of your background image of your cell.

Answer (score 1):

How About the UICollectionView instead UITableView.

Comment: I tried that through interface builder but it didn't seem to work correctly

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell.

You can either create the cell in interface builder or subclass UITableViewCell and overwrite its initWithStyle and layoutSubviews classes. You can access their properties within cellForRowAtIndexPath as usual. You could even do the layout in cellForRowAtIndexPath but I would not recommend that simply because of its bad style. For the user there would not be any difference.